# How to change total price on Order with a custom payment module?

Tags: php, module, prestashop, payment, prestashop-1.6

I made payments module with `custom currencies` (let call it `Bonus`). Products are two prices, with `local currency` and `Bonus`. Bonus value is always equal local currency `multiples by ten`.

It displays following:

> Product's Name
>
> 100,00 $
>
> (1000,00 B)

Bonus is handle by external API when my payment module is chosen. Original price is multiples by ten.

*validation.php*

```
$cart_total = $cart->getOrderTotal(TRUE, Cart::BOTH);

    $args = array(
                 'token' => $token,
                 'code' => $cardNumber,
                 'value' => $cart_total * 10,
                        );
    $response = BonusAPI::jsonResponse('decrementBonus', $args);
```

Problem starts when I want to make validate order with Bonus value.

```
$cart_total = $cart_total * 10;

$bonuspayment->validateOrder($cart->id, $state, $cart_total, $bonuspayment->displayName, NULL, NULL, $currency->id);
```

*bonuspayment.php*

```
public function hookPaymentReturn($params)
{
...
$state = $params['objOrder']->getCurrentState();
...
}
```

Then order's `$state` is 8. (error). How can I multiple cart and order amount (only for Bonus payments) and not get error state after validation?

Comment: Why you not persist the bonus in extra field?

Comment: What do you mean? $cart has only one amount, how to extend it on extra field?

Comment: Could you past all your module files so I can get a better view of the problem ?

Comment: You have error state, because the amount is different. So you need to no change this value and store this value in table eg : id_order | bonus_amount. But i don't know your requirements.

Comment: That solve problem with state. Now payments done right but in order's history I see original value. Order bases on cart, so maybe is a way to multiple amount just in cart?

Comment: like guys said above validation will not works correct with different values of cart total. In your case I would have moved on the way to create additional currency, called "Bonus", with exchange rate "default cur rate * 10" , then forcibly change `id_currency` in `Cart` object etc.

Comment: Thanks, last issue is set back default currency. Last method in payment operation is hookPaymentReturn($params) but `$cookie->id_currency = 1;` gives no result, Bonus is still setted as current currency.

Comment: DONE! :-) I used `$this->context->cookie->id_currency = 1` instead